# android how to set padding around each edge of a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have the following listview. I'd like to set space around the listview so it doesn't fill the whole screen. How can i achieve this.

I've tried every combination of padding and margins on the the listview and the parent relative layout, none seem to have an effect.

Thanks in advance Matt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >


<ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8fff"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        android:divider="#700000ff"
        android:dividerHeight="4px" >
    </ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

.Edit 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >


     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:padding="10dp">

            <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/android:list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#8fff"
                    android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
                    android:divider="#700000ff"
                    android:dividerHeight="4px" >
                </ListView>

       </RelativeLayout>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So have you give padding and margin for listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this..

```
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/android:list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#8fff"
                android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:divider="#700000ff"
                android:dividerHeight="4px" >
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your listview in one more layout and give padding to that layout..

Comment: hi, sorry it did not work, listview still fills the whole screen. the changes i made are in edit 1. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_margin="sizeindp"` 
use this it works for me [image: it look like below snapshot]
do you want to achieve this !!!!

Comment: hi where do i put the margin code, i think i have tried this

Comment: inside your Listview xml layout 

`<ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8fff"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        android:layout_margin="sizeindp" //**PUT IT HERE**//
        android:divider="#700000ff"
        android:dividerHeight="4px" >
    </ListView>`

Comment: it makes no difference

Comment: do you want to achieve what i have posted snapshot of it ? if so then the code i had given is working. & don't give the padding to Relative Layout but give the margin for ListView. it will leave space from all four side of ListView.